# How can I generate a random walk on the unitary group $U(n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

I'm interested in generating a random walk on U(n) using a computer: any references on this topic or related / requisite topics would be helpful. Specific suggestions that discuss the problem technically are welcome as well. Thank you!

**Edit:** As noted in one of the comments, I'm not looking for trivial random walks. For example, randomly alternating between $U$ and $-U$ would technically be a discrete random walk. I'd like to be able to generate a random walk that can access a dense subset of the group elements; and/or I'd like an analytical description of a continuous random walk (like a diffusion process / Brownian motion), and/or a way to simulate / approximate such a continuous process.

Comment: It's very easy to construct very trivial random walks in the unitary group.  In order to avoid those answers, it would help if you could state some properties that you might expect the random walk to have.

Comment: For instance: you may want to impose the restriction that the "reachable" elements of the walk should be dense in $U(n)$.

Comment: The proof of the [Banach-Tarski paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox#A_sketch_of_the_proof) uses a Cayley graph that may be used to generate a random walk in $SO(3)$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That's a good point. Thank you ... I'll specify that.

Comment: If you know how to generate a random walk on $\Bbb R^N$, then you can obtain a random walk on the Lie group by exponentiating a random walk on the Lie algebra. In your case the Lie algebra consists of anti-hermitian matrices, which form a real vector space.